# Is copying blob within the same Azure storage account instant?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the StartCopyFromBlob to copy a 2GB blob from container A to container B within the same storage account. I noticed that it's an instant operation as the CopyState status is Success right away. This is very good for us, so want to confirm that we can actually rely on this.

I can't find any MSDN document about this "copy optimization" when copying within the same storage account. Is there a document on this copy behavior within the same account? Just want to make sure it is officially supported.

Answer (score 2):

Only storage accounts created on or after June 7th, 2012 allow the Copy Blob operation to copy from another storage account.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894037.aspx

you might find this post interesting: Introducing Asynchronous Cross-Account Copy Blob  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx

I hope this helps let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I'm aware of cross-account copy blob support. When I copy 2GB blob cross accounts, it takes 5 minutes. However, within the same accounts, it's instant. I can't find any MSDN doc on this "instant copy". So just want to confirm that this is an documented official behavior when copying within the same account.